# How to quantify observation pairs in individuals

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to quantify observation pairs in individuals (patients). In this example I have patients who each had two different diseases. The couple of disease(that is, in the same individuals) `"a"` and `"b"` is repeated 4 times, for example, in patients `"G"`, `"H"`, `"I"` and `"J"` and the couple `"k"` and `"o"` is repeated twice (patient `"D"` has done diseases `"k"` and `"o"` and patient `"E"` has also done these two diseases).

```
Patient_ID<- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","F",
               "G","G","H","H","I","I","J","J")
Disease<-c("v","s","s","v","s","v" ,"k","o","k","o","o","s","a","b",
           "a","b","b","a","b","a")
DATA<-data.frame(Patient_ID,Disease)

print(DATA)

   Patient_ID Disease
1           A       v
2           A       s
3           B       s
4           B       v
5           C       s
6           C       v
7           D       k
8           D       o
9           E       k
10          E       o
11          F       o
12          F       s
13          G       a
14          G       b
15          H       a
16          H       b
17          I       b
18          I       a
19          J       b
20          J       a
```

With these statistics I would like to generate such a table below.

```
  a b k o v s
a 0 4 0 0 0 0
b 4 0 0 0 0 0
k 0 0 0 2 0 0
o 0 0 2 0 0 1
v 0 0 0 0 0 3
s 0 0 0 1 3 0
```

Then generate a table for only levels that have count above a certain threshold (for example 2) like in the second table (below).

```
 a b v s
a 0 4 0 0
b 4 0 0 0
v 0 0 0 3
s 0 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, use `unstack()` to transform `Disease` to a data frame with 2 columns. Remember to make both columns have equal levels. This step is to prevent dropping levels in the following operation. Then input the data frame into `table()` and it'll create a contingency table. In this table, `"a & b"` and `"b & a"` are different. To compute the total counts, you need `tab + t(tab)`.

```
pair <- data.frame(t(unstack(DATA, Disease ~ Patient_ID)))
pair[] <- lapply(pair, factor, levels = levels(DATA$Disease))
tab <- table(pair)
tab + t(tab)

#    X2
# X1  a b k o s v
#   a 0 4 0 0 0 0
#   b 4 0 0 0 0 0
#   k 0 0 0 2 0 0
#   o 0 0 2 0 1 0
#   s 0 0 0 1 0 3
#   v 0 0 0 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `table`+`crossprod`, i.e.,

```
res <- `diag<-`(crossprod(table(DATA)),0)
```

which gives

```
> res
       Disease
Disease a b k o s v
      a 0 4 0 0 0 0
      b 4 0 0 0 0 0
      k 0 0 0 2 0 0
      o 0 0 2 0 1 0
      s 0 0 0 1 0 3
      v 0 0 0 0 3 0
```

For the subset by given threshold, you can use

```
th <- 2
inds <- rowSums(res > th)>0
subset_res <- subset(res,inds,inds)
```

which gives

```
> subset_res
       Disease
Disease a b s v
      a 0 4 0 0
      b 4 0 0 0
      s 0 0 0 3
      v 0 0 3 0
```

Comment: Thank you @TomasIsCoding